# What does Java InetSocketAddress look like .toString()?

Tags: java, inet-socket

I'm doing a .toString() on an InetSocketAddress. This is part of an Android websocket client that so far is failing to connect to the host.

Right now the output from a variable address.toString() looks like `domain.com/72.xx.xxx.xx:8000` but from what I understand there needs to be two values (IP and port) only?

Thanks letting me know if this looks correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The toString() of InetSocketAddress first calls the toString() of InetAddress and then appends the port number to it and the string returned from toString() of InetAddress is of the form: **hostname / literal IP address**.

Later port number is concatenated before returning from the InetSocketAddress's toString() to the returned value (from the toString() of InetAddress), hence the final result is **hostname / literal IP address:port number**.

For more information see the JavaDocs for [InetSocketAddress's toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#toString%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find an example: http://discuss.itacumens.com/index.php?topic=46099.0

Basically it is correct :)

I'll need to debug elsewhere...